# Storage::disk Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, ubuntu

Estoy tratando de almacenar un archivo en una carpeta creada recientemente en tiempo de ejecución de la siguiente manera :

```
                                \Storage::disk('archivos_contratos')->put('/' . $contrato->id . '/' . $nombre,  \File::get($file));
```

$contrato->id es aleatorio ya que viene de una instancia anterior, aqui viene el problema:

En Windows funciona bien hace lo que requiero(crea solo la carpeta con el nombre $contrato->id dentro del disco y guarda el archivo en esa carpeta) pero en Ubuntu crea todas las subcarpetas hasta llegar a la carpeta deseada de esta manera por **ejemplo**:

C:\Uusario\Desktop\Proyecto\storage\app\archivos_contratos\18\mji_archivo.jpg

Alguna idea como resolver ?

Comment: Revisaste si Laravel espera la ruta con o sin slash al inicio? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#the-local-driver. Habría que empezar por eso.

Comment: Asegúrate de que el disco ```archivos_contratados``` esté definido también en la instalación de Laravel de Ubuntu, y en general que los valores por defecto en el archivo de configuración ```config/filesystems.php``` sean los correctos.